# Best way to compose MongoDB with ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search

I'm working on a new version of a project, so i have a lot of old data that should i migrate to the new version. The old version developed with PHP+MySql, and the new one is with MEAN.
Now i want to implement full-text search in this project, and for that decided to use ElasticSearch.
After i have googled, found that we have 5 way to compose MongoDB with ElasticSearch, and now my question is which one is the best way according to my need?
for any idea and suggestion thanks.